# How to grab images from D3 array and access via d.properties?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to add photos to my D3 javascript array, so that later on I can use d3.properties to get the photo to appear when I hover my mouse over the specific country. Currently I am accessing the names and the rank by doing d.properties.rank and d.properties.name, but I want to add a field flag: to my array and then access the d.properties.flag also.

Here is my array, I tried adding it as I would in html, by doing flag:  but that did not work, I tried using a html link, the direct link, and also the photo/forum link, but nothing I found worked.

```
var data2 = [{name:"United Kingdom", country_code: 826, rank: 1},{name:"United States", country_code: 840, rank: 2},{name:"Sweden", country_code: 752, rank: 3},
{name:"Canada", country_code: 124, rank: 4},{name:"Germany", country_code: 276, rank: 5},{name:"South Korea", country_code: 410, rank: 6},
{name:"Australia", country_code: 036, rank: 7},{name:"Italy", country_code: 380, rank: 8},
{name:"Ireland", country_code: 372, rank: 9},{name:"Jamaica", country_code: 388, rank: 10},
{name:"India", country_code: 356, rank: 11},{name:"Mexico", country_code: 484, rank: 12},{name:"France", country_code: 250, rank: 13},
{name:" Japan", country_code: 392, rank: 14},{name:"Finland", country_code: 246, rank: 15},
{name:"Spain", country_code: 724, rank: 16},{name:"Russia", country_code: 643, rank: 17},
{name:"Philippines", country_code: 608, rank: 18},{name:"Romania", country_code: 642, rank: 19},
```

Here is my code for accessing the data of the array,

```
country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {
      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

             if (d.properties.color) {
              tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name + " " + "Rank" + " " + d.properties.color);
             }
             else {
              tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name); 
             }
      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      });
```

Maybe this isnt possible, but I figure it would be.

Thank you very much!

Entire Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 World Map Template | TechSlides</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/terryCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Top 20 Countries with the most popular music</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);


var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);

function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([(width/2), (height/2)])
    .scale( width / 2 / Math.PI);

  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .on("click", click)
      .append("g");

  g = svg.append("g");

}

d3.json("data/world-topo-min.json", function(error, world) {

  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);

});




function redraw() {
  width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
  height = width / 2;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  setup(width,height);
  draw(topo);
}


function move() {

  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale; 
  zscale = s;
  var h = height/4;


  t[0] = Math.min(
    (width/height)  * (s - 1), 
    Math.max( width * (1 - s), t[0] )
  );

  t[1] = Math.min(
    h * (s - 1) + h * s, 
    Math.max(height  * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1])
  );

  zoom.translate(t);
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

  //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
  d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / s);

}



var throttleTimer;
function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
    throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      redraw();
    }, 200);
}


//geo translation on mouse click in map
function click() {
  var latlon = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  console.log(latlon);
}


  //conditional in case a point has no associated text
  if(text.length>0){

    gpoint.append("text")
          .attr("x", x+2)
          .attr("y", y+2)
          .attr("class","text")
          .text(text);
  }

}

var data2 = [{name:"United Kingdom", country_code: 826, rank: 1},{name:"United States", country_code: 840, rank: 2},{name:"Sweden", country_code: 752, rank: 3},
{name:"Canada", country_code: 124, rank: 4},{name:"Germany", country_code: 276, rank: 5},{name:"South Korea", country_code: 410, rank: 6},
{name:"Australia", country_code: 036, rank: 7},{name:"Italy", country_code: 380, rank: 8},
{name:"Ireland", country_code: 372, rank: 9},{name:"Jamaica", country_code: 388, rank: 10},
{name:"India", country_code: 356, rank: 11},{name:"Mexico", country_code: 484, rank: 12},{name:"France", country_code: 250, rank: 13},
{name:" Japan", country_code: 392, rank: 14},{name:"Finland", country_code: 246, rank: 15},
{name:"Spain", country_code: 724, rank: 16},{name:"Russia", country_code: 643, rank: 17},
{name:"Philippines", country_code: 608, rank: 18},{name:"Romania", country_code: 642, rank: 19},
{name:"Ukraine", country_code: 804, rank: 20}];

function draw(topo) {

  svg.append("path")
     .datum(graticule)
     .attr("class", "graticule")
     .attr("d", path);


  g.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 0], [-90, 0], [0, 0], [90, 0], [180, 0]]})
   .attr("class", "equator")
   .attr("d", path);


    d3.json("world-map.json", function(json) {
                //Merge the rank in data2 and GeoJSON in a single array
                //Loop through once for each "rank" data value
                for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
                    //Grab country name
                    var data2CountryCode = data2[i].country_code;
                    //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                    var datarank = +data2[i].rank;
                    //Find the corresponding country inside the GeoJSON
                    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                        //We'll check the official ISO country code
                        var jsonCountryCode = json.features[j].properties.un_a3;

                        if (data2CountryCode == jsonCountryCode) {
                            //Copy the data2 rank value into the GeoJSON, with the name "color"
                            json.features[j].properties.color = datarank;
                            //Stop looking through the JSON
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

var color = d3.scale.quantize()
            .range(["Lime","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","LightGreen","LimeGreen","Green","DarkGreen","Yellow","Gold",
            "GoldenRod","DarkGoldenRod","Orange"    
,"DarkOrange","Coral","Red","OrangeRed","Tomato","Crimson","DarkRed","Brown"])
.domain([(d3.min(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; })),(d3.max(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; }))
]); 
         var country = g.selectAll(".country")
                   .data(json.features) //in my example, json.features
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .on("click", function(d,i){
                    console.log("Population for " + d.properties.name + " is " + d.properties.pop_est + " as of " + d.properties.lastcensus)
                    })
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {

                        //Get data value
                        var value = d.properties.color;
                        if (value) {
                            //If value exists…
                            return color(value);
                        } else {
                            //do nothing, leave country as is
                        }

      });


  //offsets for tooltips
  var offsetL = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft+20;
  var offsetT = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop+10;

  //tooltips
  //modified to display rank of country, if it has one, if not, doesnt display any rank
  country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {
      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

             if (d.properties.color) {
              tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name + " " + "Rank" + " " + d.properties.color);
             }
             else {
              tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name); 
             }
      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      }); 
});
}

</script>
<p id="legend"><img src="images/legend.png" alt="Legend"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no `properties` function in d3. are you using some plugin or some other code that is creating this `properties` property for every object

Comment: I am using json and topojson

Comment: How are you adding those properties to your topojson?  Do you have a *complete* reproducible sample of your code?

Comment: I added my entire code in the OP, sorry just unsure of your question